# Placing objects automatically when ground plane detected with vuforia

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

I'm working on an application where the concept is that you can 'select' objects before actually placing them. So what I wanted to do was have some low quality objects on a shelf or something like it. When the user selects the object he then can tap to place the high quality version of the object in his area for further viewing.

I was wondering if it's possible with vuforia. I wanted to use this platform since it works well from what I could tell and it's cross platform (The application needs to be for android and the HoloLens).

I have set up the basic application where you can place a capsule in the area. Now I wanted to automatically place the (in this case capsule) once vuforia has detected a ground plane. From what I could see the plane finder has events that go off when an input is detected, but I couldn't find an event that goes off when the ground plane is detected. Is it still possible with vuforia? I know it's doable with the HoloLens, but I would like to know if it's possible for android or other mobile devices. I really don't know where to start/look for so I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Let me know if I need to include more information!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Vuforia `PlaneFinderBehaviour` (see doc [here](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/reference/unity/classVuforia_1_1PlaneFinderBehaviour.html#a30df5402ae1ab108127fc11996529f49)) has the event `OnAutomaticHitTest` which fires every frame a ground plane is detected. 
So you can use it to automatically spawn an object.

You have to add your method in the `On Automatic Hit Test` instead of the `On Interactive Hit Test` list of the "Plane Finder":

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this would work, but I'm looking for a method or event that indicates when the ground plane is 'stable' enough to place models on

Comment: If the Vuforia PlaneFinderBehaviour fires one of its events (OnInteractiveHitTest or OnAutomaticHitTest) a plane was found and you can place content on it (at least this frame long). There is no such information how 'stable' your plane is.

Comment: What you could do is measure how many frames in a row the OnAutomaticHitTest fires and conclude from this how steady your plane is. ... But i doubt the benefit of something like this ...

Comment: From manual testing I found that the ground plane isn't stable for a few seconds. The hologram moves and such. If I wait and then place it, it's usually more stable. Maybe it has something to do with my environment. I'll mark your answer since it's the closest thing to what I need

Comment: We noticed the same thing regarding ground plane stability.  Our solution was to count 30 frames of continuous 'Automatic Hit Test Results'.  Once that was achieved, then we would allow placing objects.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that vuforia fusion, does not yet support ARCore (it supports ARKit) so it uses an internal implementation to simulate ARCore functionality, and they are waiting for a final release of ARCore to support it. Many users reported that their objects move even when they use an ARCore supported device.